# Keyboard shortcuts only work when an application is open on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 22.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. For some reason, when nothing is open on the desktop, my shortcuts to launch applications (such as  Ulauncher and guake terminal) don't work. If I open Chrome or Firefox the shortcuts are working.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same issue, I tried installing both -
22.04 and 22.10, both gave the same issue.

I tried installing Guake Terminal, F12 is supposed to prompt up the terminal, but it does this only when I'm focused on another app like 'FireFox','Chrome',etc.
When opening 'Settings' for example, the same bug occurs and I'm not able to use F12 to pop up the terminal.

Tried to debug it a bit with `xev` and things like that but to no avail.

I just decided to revert to 20.04.5, and it solved it self magically.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 05/11/2023

I just disabled Wayland and everything worked.

Just open custom.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

And uncomment this line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

It must looks like this now

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Restart and hopefully, keyboard shortcuts will work again.

### Old

This issue is explained in this other thread:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1465157

> The issues with the many launchers you tried is likely related to the
> fact that Ubuntu 22.04 runs on Wayland, a newer display system
> replacing the classical X11 system.
>
> Wayland does not (yet) support that applications set a global shortcut
> key.

Unfortunately, it seems like there isn't a fix yet.